# Android can't read data collection from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here][1]I have problem that I can't read/write to firebase I already tried alot of variant of сode to fix the issue, all looks like as proper, and sdk implemented as proper, and I don't get any expectation, in Manifest has network permission.
its never enters to override function it just skip it, which issue may occurs?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDc3o.png

```
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
  db.collection("Account")
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    Log.d("sad", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.w("TAG", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you share your Firestore security rules?

Comment: Sure, I don't get any error, when I debugging I see the code enters to  db.collection("Account").get(), and than just skip over on all the other logical to end of the funcation


rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 4, 14);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Is your `onComplete` even triggered?